# issue with VBA Copy specific row/column from Word table (with merged rows) to Excel

Tags: excel, merge, ms-word, copy, vba

I have a Word document (*.docx) with a table

```
**Name  Description Dimension**

Level   Text 1  Text 11 
        Text 2  Text 12 
        Text 3  Text 13 
        Text 4  Text 14 
        Text 5  Text 15 
        Text 6  Text 16 
test    Text 7  Text 17
```

having 3 columns and 8 rows.

I would like to extract to Excel only the content of the column "Description" for which the column "Name" contains "test".

I did the following Excel Marco

```
    Sub ImportWordTable()

    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
    Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
    Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
    Dim resultRow As Long
    Dim tableStart As Integer
    Dim tableTot As Integer
    Dim nextRow As Integer 'row index in Excel

    On Error Resume Next

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents


    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ")
    ' Create Heading
        HeadingRow = 1

        .Cells(HeadingRow, 1).Formula = "Identifier"

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

    With wdDoc
        TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
        tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
        If TableNo = 0 Then
            MsgBox "The document contains no tables", _
            vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
        ElseIf TableNo >= 1 Then
            TableNo = MsgBox("The document contains in TOTAL: " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf)
        End If

        resultRow = 2

        For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
            With .tables(tableStart)
                'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells


                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                'determine if the text of the 1th column contains the words "mike"


                    If (.cell(iRow, 1).Range.Text Like "*test*") _
                    Then
                         nextRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


                    'find the last empty row in the current worksheet
                         nextRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                         MsgBox nextRow
                    'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells

                         For iCol = 1 To 2
                            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(nextRow, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)

                         Next iCol
                     Else
                        MsgBox "do not containt the word *test*"
                     End If
                Next iRow
            End With
        Next tableStart



End With
End With

End Sub
```

but the result is not what I expected. It is:

```
Identifier
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
Text 5
Text 6
Text 7
```

And I would expect

```
Identifier
Text 7
```

Could you please help me ?

It look likes that this comes from the fact that my rows in Word are "merged". If I split them I receive what I expect but the problem is that I have about 300 tables so i can not split them one by one ...

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try after adding "." (Dot) for the line : If (.cell(iRow, 1).Range.Text Like "*.test.*") _

Comment: It is not working ...  Identifier
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
Text 5
Text 6

Comment: CAn you be specific, what are you getting

Comment: Identifier Text 2 Text 3 Text 4 Text 5 Text 6

Comment: Use Instr function, this is much easier
If Instr(.cell(iRow, 1).Range.Text, "test")

Comment: unfortunately I still have the same result as in the beginning:  Identifier
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
Text 5
Text 6
Text 7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149816/discussion-between-lilly-and-nishit-dey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below code

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
On Error Resume Next
wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "Identifier"
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file
                inRow = 2
                inCol = 1
With wdDoc
   TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
   If TableNo = 0 Then
       MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
       vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
   ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
       TableNo = MsgBox("The document contains in TOTAL: " & TableNo & " 
         tables." & vbCrLf) 
   End If
 For tbl = 1 To wdDoc.tables.Count
With .tables(tbl)
    'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            Debug.Print InStr(UCase(WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)), "TEST") & "    " & _
            WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text) & "      " & _
            WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol + 1).Range.Text) & "      " & _
            iRow & "  "; iCol
            com = InStr(UCase(WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)), "TEST")
            If com = 1 Then
                Cells(inRow, inCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol + 1).Range.Text)
                'Cells(iRow, iCol + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol + 2).Range.Text)
                inRow = inRow + 1

            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
End With
Next
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the If condition code from the below to the edited version

```
If (.cell(iRow, 1).Range.Text Like "*test*") _
            Then
```

Edited:

```
If Instr(UCase(.cell(iRow, 1).Range.Text),Ucase("test")) _
            Then
```

Let me know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but not working probably because I have merged lines and not proper grid lines in the "Level" columns.